# WiX CLR CustomAction sometime fails to log

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In my WiX projects I have two custom actions, in the same DLL. Both are written in C#.

The first one enumerates which IIS-sites are available on the machine. It runs before the Windows Installer dialogs.

The second one runs after a dialog "select which web-site", i.e. in the Dialog-flow as a result of pressing "Next".

The first one logs nicely to the MSI-logfile.
The second one logs nothing at all.

Why cannot my custom action log during the dialog-part? (The rest of the dialog-part is logging as expected.)
Is there something I can do to enable this logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom actions can't write to the MSI log when they're invoked using a DoAction control event. It's an MSI limitation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permissions problem.

IIS web site enumeration requires Administrator privileges, so the first custom action runs in an elevated process. Your second custom action runs in a non-elevated process, so it doesn't have enough permissions to write in your log.

If you create the log in a per-user location, for example the current user desktop, the second action will successfully write in the log.

A solution is to use an elevated process for your second custom action. Another solution is to always create the log in a per-user location.